# change app description text of published app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'd like to change the description text of my already published Windows Phone app; is this possible or do I have to submit a new version? I found the according details in the dashboard for my app, but no possibility to change the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to Update the description text of the App published in the Windows Phone Store,

- Click on the App name from the dashboard, Which you want to change the description text.
- Then click on the "**Update app**", Which will open the Update app page.
- Now click on the "**Upload and describe your package(s)**" Section, Which will take you to the next page where you can change the description of your application

You do not need to submit the new version of the app,
Just change the description text and click on the save button

Comment: thanks! "Review and submit" (https://cloudup.com/ceNbP5XKnOq) isn't necessary for sure?

Comment: Yes it is necessary,
if you upload the new XAP, the store will take the time to verify,
but in the case of Information change/update, it'll Review and submit within 2hrs